# MVC ASP 3 table join then display results

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

For a project, I'm displaying books for adding to basket. I need to join 3 tables in order to show the formats available: I do: Books to BookFormats on bookID, then BookFormats to Format on formatID. This is a prelaid out database which i cannot change. I wrote a LINQ  query to display them all and made a view model with the properties of all 3.

**The linq query:**

```
        IEnumerable<BookAndFormatViewModel> IEBooksRepository.GetAllBooksWithFormats()
    {
        var query =
            from book in eBooks.Books
            join format in eBooks.BookFormats on book.BookID equals format.BookID
            join formatName in eBooks.Formats on format.FormatID equals formatName.FormatID
            select new BookAndFormatViewModel();
        return query.ToList();
```

**The view model for the three:**

```
    public int BookID { get; set; }
    public string ReferenceNumber { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int FormatID { get; set; }
    public string FormatType { get; set; }
```

**The controller code:**

```
        IEnumerable<BookModel> books = repository.GetAllBooks();
        IEnumerable<BookAndFormatViewModel> booksWithFormat = repository.GetAllBooksWithFormats();

        if (books.Count() == 0)
        {
            return PartialView("NoBooks");

        }
        return PartialView("Books", booksWithFormat);
```

When I run it it displays empty data just 0's and null fields.

Comment: This line: `select new BookAndFormatViewModel()` is creating an empty model, you haven't assigned any values to the properties yet e.g. `BookId = book.Id, ReferenceNumber = book.RefNo` etc

Comment: @markpsmith If i added in parameters for the constructor wouldn't it only make one entry? Would there be a way to add in every entry?

Comment: It would create a  `List<BookAndFormatViewModel>`

Answer (score 0):

The fix in the end was to change the constructor of the model and then create the model like so:

```
            var query =
            from book in eBooks.Books
            join format in eBooks.BookFormats on book.BookID equals format.BookID
            join formatName in eBooks.Formats on format.FormatID equals formatName.FormatID
            select new BookAndFormatViewModel
            {
                BookID = book.BookID,
                ReferenceNumber = book.ReferenceNumber,
                Title = book.Title,
                Price = book.Price,
                FormatID = format.FormatID,
                FormatType = formatName.FormatType
            };
```